# PreferenceActivity not displayed (Blank Screen)

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, preferencescreen

I am following these [instructions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) to create a **PreferenceActivity** but the PereferenceActivity is not displayed. Activity starts but the **Layout is blank**.

1. I am also using material design NavDrawer in my Application by referring to developer.android.com but i hope it doesn't affect
2. I am testing application on device running Kitkat
3. Here is what happens when i launch PreferenceActivity ["screenshot"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9AqE.png)
4. Logcat:
   `Could not find method android.preference.PreferenceActivity.onCreate
   VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 950: Landroid/preference/PreferenceActivity;.onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;)V`

Code:

### app_preference.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Settings">
    <ListPreference
            android:title="Timer"
            android:summary="@string/timer_summary"
            android:key="prefTime"
            android:defaultValue="30"
            android:entries="@array/prefTime"
            android:entryValues="@array/prefTimeValue"/>
    <SwitchPreference
            android:title="Shuffle"
            android:summary="@string/shuffle_summary"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="prefToggleShuffle"/>
    <SwitchPreference
            android:title="Allow over Wifi-only"
            android:summary="@string/wifi_only_summary"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="prefWifiOnly"/>
    <Preference
            android:title="Restore Defaults"
            android:summary="@string/restore_summ"/>
    <Preference
            android:title="Clear Data"
            android:summary="@string/shuffle_summary"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

### Settings.java

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
}

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preference);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

### Mainfest.xml

```
.....
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
<activity android:name=".preferences.Settings>
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                   android:value=".activity.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
.....
```

### Calling Intent

```
case R.id.action_setting:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SETTINGS);//RESULT_SETTINGS = 1
            break;
```

Comment: Is this <activity android:name=".preferences.Settings> correct in the Manifest? Try <activity android:name=".Settings"> instead

Comment: Yes <activity android:name=".preferences.Settings> is correct.

Comment: You may want to check this tutorial on PreferenceActivity and PreferenceFragment [link](http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/01/preferenceactivity-preferencefragment.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delete the second parameter in onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

**Update for Aviel Fedida:**
According with [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)), `void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState, 
                PersistableBundle persistentState)` is called when the activity is being re-initialized.
So when you start a new Activity with `startActivityForResult` or `startActivity` that method is not called, and the code inside is not executed.

Black screen appears becouse `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preference);` is "unreachable code"

Comment: Hi, I had this problem as well, your solution works for me but, can you explain in your answer why the black screen appears when you use the constructor version with `PersistableBundle`, or maybe reference the some article that explains, thanks.

Comment: Hahah, liked the "Update for me", thanks so much, have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Use `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`instead of `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding the line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
```

Here I mean to add the layout file associated to your `SettingsActivity`,
inside the `OnCreate` method of the `Settings` class:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[RE-EDITED]

The main issue seems to be that you are using a `PreferenceActivity` with a `PreferenceFragment`, and you are assuming that a `PreferenceActivity` has things like action bars that you can directly access. This is probably a bad assumption.

A `PreferenceFragment` is actually meant to be used with a "regular" `Activity`, not a `PreferenceActivity`.

So, for instance, if you really want to access the action bar, you should use an [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) instead.  See also the [documentation in the API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Comment: already tried that ,doesn't work. 
Results in multiple null pointer exception across MainActivity super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); and getSupportActionBar() method

Comment: I followed documentation, removed actionBar, used a regular activity
but still doesn't work in fact every time application crashes with Null Pointer exception as i told earlier.

Comment: OK, I have modified my answer again. If you still have issues, please submit another question with full details.